# Raspberry Pi Install guvcview-src-2.0.1

Tags: installation, raspberry-pi

I'm manually installing guvcview in my Raspberry Pi. After the configure, an error showed up.

```
Package requirements (libv4l2 libudev libusb-1.0 libavcodec libpng) were not met:

No package 'libudev' found
No package 'libusb-1.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
```

Does anyone know how to manually install libudev and libusb-1.0?

Comment: Your error message has the same form of an error message used in Ubuntu, so your Raspberry Pi could be running either Debian or Ubuntu and this does not exclude Fedora, Arch, etc., but you haven't mentioned which OS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With raspian you could install libudev and libusb-1.0 using :

```
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

But probably this will not be sufficiant to build guvcview (see [README.md](http://sourceforge.net/p/guvcview/git-master/ci/master/tree/README.md))

> On most distributions you can just install the development packages:
>   intltool, autotools-dev, libsdl2-dev, libgtk-3-dev, portaudio19-dev,
>   libpng12-dev, libavcodec-dev, libavutil-dev, libv4l-dev, libudev-dev,
>   libusb-1.0-0-dev, libpulse-dev, libgsl-dev

Then in order to install the needed dependencies you should use :

```
sudo apt-get install intltool autotools-dev libsdl2-dev libgtk-3-dev portaudio19-dev libpng12-dev libavcodec-dev libavutil-dev libv4l-dev libudev-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev libpulse-dev libgsl0-dev
```